# Turning the Stripe Checkout into a Synch function

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

I am trying to use wrapAsync for Stripe.charges call using Stripe Checkout, but I cant seem to get it working

Client code
    Template.bookingPost2.events({
      "click #accept": function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();

```
    StripeCheckout.open({
      key: 'public_key',
      amount: 5000, // this is equivalent to $50
      name: 'Meteor Tutorial',
      description: 'On how to use Stripe ($50.00)',
      panelLabel: 'Pay Now',
      token: function(res) {
        stripeToken = res.id;
        console.info(res);
        Meteor.call('chargeCard', stripeToken);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Server code

```
Meteor.methods({
    'chargeCard': function(stripeToken) {
      check(stripeToken, String);
      var Stripe = StripeAPI('secret_key');

      Stripe.charges.create({
        source: stripeToken,
        amount: 5000, // this is equivalent to $50
        currency: 'usd'
      }, function(err, charge) {
        console.log(err, charge);
      });
    }
  });
```

My tried Solution:

```
  var stripeChargesCreateSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create);

  var result = stripeChargesCreateSync({
     source: stripeToken,
     amount: (info.timeRequired/15)*500, // this is equivalent to $50
     currency: 'gbp'
  });
```

And how do I handle the returned values namely charge and err?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and `result` should populate with a result as you see in the stripe documentation:

```
 var result = stripeChargesCreateSync({
     source: stripeToken,
     amount: (info.timeRequired/15)*500, // this is equivalent to $50
     currency: 'gbp'
  });
```

This is where the error is, use this:

```
var stripeChargesCreateSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create, Stripe.charges);
```

instead of

```
var stripeChargesCreateSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create);
```

Your `stripeChargesCreateSync` method needs to bind to the correct context when it runs. Meteor.wrapAsync doesn't know what that is so you need to tell it where the `Stripe.charges.create` method is.

Comment: Right, what does context mean? And how do you capture error from the call? like whether it was successful or not?

Comment: The error will be `throw`n like a normal javascript error. To get more details on it, you can use the ordinary `try..catch` pattern. When the function runs, it needs a context if it contains `this`. The second parameter, `Stripe.charges`, is set to `this`, so this is how the context comes in. The concept is slightly on the more advance side in javascript. I'd recommend reading http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/ for a better explanation on it. If it is not successful the client `Meteor.call` will fire the error callback instead of the success one